# android bitmap size exceeds vm budget

Tags: android, bitmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

why this code throw exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:bitmap size exceeds VM budget?
I just get the width and height of the view which present on the screen.
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/823966/1075066 try google first..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/823966/1441666

To fix OutOfMemory you should do something like that:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap preview_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
```

This inSampleSize option reduces memory consumption.